# Can I inspect indexeddb in firefox like how we inspect websql in resource tab of webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, firebug, indexeddb

Is there any `firebug extension` that allos me to inspect `indexed DB` in `firefox` like how we inspect `webSQL` in `webkit` browsers.

I did some Googling but couldnt find anything useful, is it too early to find `indexedDB` inspectors?

How do we check if the tables are created and populated, should we write sort of test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **Storage Inspector** you can view the indexeddb data in Firefox.

The Storage Inspector is available from Firefox 34.

For more information about [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are any extensions for it, but I wrote an indexeddb viewer a while ago. You can find it on [codeplex](http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com/releases). Information on how to use it you can find on my [blog](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/11/indexeddbviewer-take-look-inside-your.html).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Yes this would help me, i knew someone should have coded this already. Thanks.

Comment: what is `linq2indexedDB` ?

Comment: This is an indexeddb wrapper. It provides an easy to use query interface with some extra features. The core is the wrapper for cross browser support